# how to divide tasks between two computers based on their speed in MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am programming in MPI, with two different computers. At the first I want to measure the speed of each computer dynamically, and after that divide the file which they should read between them based on their speed.(the faster computer should read more volume) For this approach I've written a sort program. Each computer runs it individually,in the beginning of the program, but after that I should send the execution time of each computer for the other one,to divide the file between them.in fact I  want to use a code like this:

```
MPI::init();
.....

sort();
t= time of sort() execution ;
MPI_send("t");///I want to send the time of execution for the other computer here;
MPI_recieve("time");//I want to receive the time of execution from another computer //here;
.........
```

but it doesn't work correctly, Because I don't know which computer will finish the program sooner, it becomes a little complex. What is the best solution for this object?

Comment: The efficiency that you measure with one problem type will not transfer over to the other. The more different the real problem and the benchmark, the greater discrepancy between actual results and the benchmark. You also bring it to the extreme. You benchmark computational efficiency (sorting) and use it to judge efficiency in I/O problem (reading the file). You should benchmark with a test resembling the actual task as close as possible.

Comment: what does it mean" You should benchmark with a test resembling the actual task as close as possible" can you explain more about that? I think for this approach it is enough to send the execution time of sort program for another computer.

Comment: Sorting stuff, which is most likely bound by RAM memory latencies, computing which is also most likely bound by memory, but also depends heavily on code quality and computing kernels preparation, and reading files from disks which is I/O bound, will yield incomparable processing efficiency information. E.g: One computer can have fast SSD drives, and read files fast, the other can have fast CPU but old HDD, and will sort and compute stuff fast, but read files slowly.

Comment: that was a good point,but from dividing the file in my program,I mean the amount of processing will become more for the other hand,because i read the whole  file just one time in each computer,after that i will divide the data between them to process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Way 1. Rank `master` computes the distribution.

You can run the program in the benchmark mode once to have an estimated performance for each machine in a cluster. Then use `MPI_Gather` to get data to the `master` rank, or whatever you like. Now you can save it to a file for latter use, or keep in memory, if you continue execution.

Rank `master` can compute the bounduaries for each MPI task and use `MPI_Scatter` to distrubte them back.

#### Way 2. Each MPI task computes the distribution.

Alternatively you can distribute all the benchmark results to all MPI tasks, and if they all use the same algorithm to compute bounduaries, they can computer their own, knowing what all other tasks' "speed" is.

If you had the benchmark results saved in a file on rank `master` you can just `MPI_Broadcast` them. (Might as well use **Way 1** if that's the case.) If you run the benchmark before every computation you can use `MPI_Allgather` to distribute them to each other MPI task.

*Sidenote:* Also please take into consideration that the benchmark should reflect the actual task performed. You cannot benchmark for problem 1 and expect the same efficiency for problem 2. And most certainly you cannot draw serious conclusions how fast HDD I/O will go based on purely memory-bound benchmark that sorting is. There are also computational tasks that can be either memory or CPU bound. On one machine they can be CPU bound, and on the other memory, and depending on the CPU architecture, code, and machine itself. That is why the benchmark should resemble the actual task, and should be chosen wisely and carefully if you really care about performance.

Sometimes changing the size of the problem can cause surprising results because the data will fit into cache for small problems and won't for bigger, and you can observe big drop in performance, based on the *critical* problem size. And the critical problem size can differ from machine to machine. It is not easy.

Comment: thank you,but i should say there are just tow computers,and after dividing the information between the computers I have a lot of send an d receive,but my major problem is that I don't know which sort program will finish sooner,and how should I wrote the send()and receive() for getting the time of each other?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple task (calculating pi or something to X decimal places) and distribute to all nodes, have each node record start and finish time, then gather all the results (being the time taken).

When you gather the results, the root node will block until all items are received.

Comment: Benchmarking with a different problem is a bad idea IMO. The results will vary depending on the problem type.

Answer (score 0):

You may split your task to many small tasks (not too small, or overhead will be too large), and then each process will ask for a task and process it (something like thread pool, but using processes). But it is quite difficult and in fact, MPI is practically never used for different-speed computers because of it.

Comment: On the contrary, implementing the "manager-worker" pattern as it is called is relatively easy and is often used on heterogeneous systems with those becoming more and more widespread.